# What's the Issuer name of service bus in LOB Setting

Tags: azure, biztalk, servicebus, azureservicebus

I'm new to Azure Biztalk Service. While creating SQL LOB in Azure BizTalk Adapter Service (localhost:8080),
[image]

I got the below errors.

Service Bus in Azure now has only SAS, What's the Issuer name of service bus in LOB Setting? I used SAS account and got the below security token error.

```
500

Code: '13' 
Message: 'Error occurred while trying to bring up the relay service. Error Message: 'The request was aborted: The request was canceled.

Server Error in '/elainedev_orderproce~_e1ccffe4ff14482ba3578aece913d975' Application.

The request was aborted: The request was canceled.

 Description: 
An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

 Exception Details: 
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.]
 System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context) +334
 System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +21
 Microsoft.ServiceBus.TokenRequestAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__4(TokenRequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r) +25
 Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.EnumerateSteps(CurrentThreadType state) +881

[SecurityTokenException: The token provider was unable to provide a security token while accessing 'https://elainedev-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net/WRAPv0.9/'. Token provider returned message: 'The request was aborted: The request was canceled.'.]
 Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +774
 Microsoft.ServiceBus.RelayedOnewayTcpListenerClient.Connect(TimeSpan timeout) +425
 Microsoft.ServiceBus.RelayedOnewayTcpClient.EnsureConnected(TimeSpan timeout, Boolean isRetry) +589
 Microsoft.ServiceBus.RelayedOnewayTcpClient.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +12
 System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +307
 Microsoft.ServiceBus.RelayedOnewayTcpListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +15
 Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.RefcountedCommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +435
 Microsoft.ServiceBus.RelayedOnewayChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +117
 System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +307
 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +73
 System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +307
 System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +130
 System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +307
 Microsoft.ServiceBus.RelayedSocketListener.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +15
 Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.BufferedConnectionListener.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +23
 Microsoft.ServiceBus.SocketConnectionTransportManager.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +584
 Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TimeSpan timeout, TransportChannelListener channelListener) +572
 Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(TimeSpan timeout, SelectTransportManagersCallback selectTransportManagerCallback) +210
 Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.TransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +104
 Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.ConnectionOrientedTransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +63
 Microsoft.ServiceBus.SocketConnectionChannelListener`2.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +63
 System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +307
 Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.LayeredChannelListener`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +81
 System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +307
 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +73
 System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +307
 System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +130
 System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +307
 System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +130
 System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +740

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/elainedev_orderproce~_e1ccffe4ff14482ba3578aece913d975/RuntimeService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation. The exception message is: The token provider was unable to provide a security token while accessing 'https://elainedev-sb.accesscontrol.windows.net/WRAPv0.9/'. Token provider returned message: 'The request was aborted: The request was canceled.'..]
 System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +466
 System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +100
 System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +241
 System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult ar) +39
 System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +166

Version Information:
 Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.57.0'.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use ACS authentication for Service Bus if you create the Service Bus namespace using Powershell. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn170478.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Go to Azure PowerShell

```
PS C:\> Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile
PS C:\> Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile "C:\mine.publishsettings"
PS C:\> Get-AzureSubscription
PS C:\> Select-AzureSubscription "Visual Studio Ultimate with MSDN"
PS C:\> New-AzureSBNamespace -Name elainedev1 -Location "East Asia" -CreateACSNamespace $true -NamespaceType Messaging
```

Notice it's only used to create a new service bus namespace, cannot create ACS account for existing service bus.